# SVG image with fluid width and fixed height (stretch/shrink with page but keep height)

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG image that I am trying to use in my page that I would like to stretch with page. The same CSS that works with non-SVG images doesn't work for the SVG. As seen in the quick fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/TUby3/

My HTML

```
<img src="image.svg" id="topHeader">
```

My CSS

```
#topHeader {
width: calc(85% + 10px);
height: 46px;
}
```

I've been trying different things in my CSS but can't seem to get anything to work. When I make the page smaller, the width of the image does get smaller but the height does not stay fixed, the height shrinks in uniform with the width.

Does anyone know a solution to this that does not involve trading the SVG for a PNG or JPEG?

Comment: What if you try setting it as a background image?

Comment: What if you set a min-height on the image?

Comment: The same thing happens for the most part.

Comment: Min-height does not work either.

Comment: I've also tried playing with a wrap div around the image, nothing happening there either.

Comment: It works in my fiddle.

Comment: So what’s the desired result – do you want that Napoleon face to be stretched reeeaaally wide, or what?

Comment: Ha, yeah. I was just using it as an example SVG

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TUby3/1/

Just put a div with a set height around it.

```
html
    <div id="test">
     Your Image
    </div>
css 
    #test{
    height:"60px;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if that fiddle is working on your end, but it doesn't seem to be working on mine, or in my html file.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve the same effect you are after by setting it as a background image to a div and using the background-size css...

```
background:url(http://www.adobe.com/inspire-apps/exporting-svg-illustrator-0913/fig14/img/napoleon%20for%20svg%201.svg) left top no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
```

(That said, Mark's solution works fine for me in Chrome)